# Android Google Tango Set object position wrt Area Description File

Tags: java, android, google-project-tango, rajawali

Im in this situation, I have an ADF with some 3D object on it (I have the positions of objects saved on DB), now what Im doing is loading ADF,waitting to LOCALIZE and putting 3D objects on it but every time I run the app object appears in different places and I noticed that this depends on the orientation/pose of smartphone when it starts, so in few words how to take in account device pose/orientation and put 3D object in Rajawali3D(graphic engine) with respect to that pose?

Answer (score 0):

Under Unity I had the same problem, I fixed it by checking the "Use Area description" in the Tango Pose Controller prefab. What this does, is that it changes the Frame of reference that Tango is using to localize itself: indeed instead of TANGO_START_OF_SERVICE you need to use TANGO_AREA_DESCRIPTION as a base reference frame.

Comment: yes I know , I using that TangoCoordinateFramePair(TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,TangoPoseData.COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE), maby Im doing something wrong when I get 3DObject coordinates because I think that Im getting coordinates of object in scene and not with respect to ADF